# copy data from cassandra to cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I had a production cluster of 20 nodes with 3 replication and I want to copy a part of data i.e, ~600GB ( with 3 replication ) to my test environment with only 1 replication.

I know we can use sstableloader but do we need to copy all the 600GB over network to the other cluster?

Is their a way to move only one copy of data to other cluster?

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your are using RandomPartitioner. What you are doing depends on how many nodes are in your test environment.

In case of SimpleStrategy:

A. If you are using 20 nodes in your test environment:

1. Assign same token to each node in your test environment;
2. Use nodetool snapshot on all nodes at the same time;
3. Copy the data from snapshot directories from your production node with the same token to the test node with the same token;
4. To change the replication factor to 1, simply update the keyspace with new replication setting like here:http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Replication
5. Run cleanup on each node.

B. If you are using less number of nodes than production:

1. Evenly assign tokens to new nodes to get a balanced ring;
2. Use nodetool snapshot on all nodes at the same time;
3. You will have to copy all the data from all the nodes in production to each node in your test environment;
4. If you are using LevelCompaction, make sure you remove metadata.json from the date directory of the column family using that compaction before starting the node. This make LevelCompaction to compact and group the labels correctly on your new setup.
5. Same as 4 above;
6. Same as 5 above;

You can skip the snapshot and copy the data directories straight over if you don't care about consistency of data at a point in time in your restored version for testing.

Things to consider:

This process effects your Disk I/O dramatically. If you are doing it on a live cluster, use the snapshot to at least lock the state at a point in time and copy gradually.

In case of NetworkTopologyStrategy:

You can repeat the process above but only copy from combination of nodes that are in one rack and form 100% of data. If you absolutely care about possible missed writes to nodes on other racks that were not replication to the nodes in this rack, then you will have to copy everything from all the nodes like above.

Ideal solution:

If you are going to do this every day for testing like I do for my company, you want to make some automation around it. The best automation for backup and restore in my opinion is Netflix's Priam https://github.com/Netflix/Priam

I have production backups stored in S3. Code will bring up new machines in test, assigns the same token for one zone and I set the priam snapshot time to the range from last day's backup, then the test nodes will automatically receive the data from s3 backups.

Hope my answer helped you.

Comment: Thank you arya. but we using murmur3partitioner and vnodes not the tokens. we are using SimpleStrategy and CF with size tiered compaction. I had only 3 nodes in the test cluster. How can I copy 20 nodes data into 3 nodes. Do I need to distribute the data into 3 nodes?